# Adding tables on the master - mysql database replication

Tags: mysql-replication, mysql

I have a simple MySQL replication system set up with a single master and a single slave.  If I add a table to the master, will it show up on the slave?  If I add a column, will it show up on the slave?  How about deletes?

This question can be encapsulated in:

How exactly do schema changes work in simple MySQL replication systems?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, schema changes replicate as any other event.  MySQL slaves replicate master's binary logs into a relay log and then executes the events.  Of course, this is if `replicate-do-db` or another variable identifies the specific scope in question to execute the statements.

There was a bug in MySQL, where if you executed alterations by specifying the table as `database.table`, it would not replicate.  It required a `use` statement to proceed the queries that matched a `replicate-do` variable to actually execute the queries.  I believe this is addressed in the current version but is still something to be aware of.

This functionality is [well documented](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-implementation.html) on the MySQL Web site.

Comment: I ran into this bug yesterday myself. At least I assume that is the issue. Our replication, according to master and slave status, is working properly. However, there is a data discrepancy. Basically I did this:
update ss_central.styles set style_css = (select style_css from `central_bak_7-14-10-2`.styles where                 
style_number = $style_number) where style_number = $style_number

Answer (score 0):

If you add a table to the master, it will show up on the slave. If you add a column, it will show up on the slave. If you delete a column, it will delete from the slave.

Without replication filters, MySQL replicates all data and schema changes. Creation and deletion of databases too.

Having said that, I strongly advocate against replication filters.

See [MySQL says replication is fine but data is not copied](https://serverfault.com/questions/194947/mysql-says-replication-is-fine-but-data-is-not-copied/203189#203189)

For most applications, leaving it wide open is perfectly fine.